# Compounding a gamma distribution with another distribution to yield a gamma

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

I have a gamma distributed random variable $X$, with its mean $\mu$ distributed as some other function
$$
X \sim \text{Gamma}(\mu,k)\\
\mu \sim P(\theta)
$$

What is the distribution $P(\theta)$ such that when I marginalize out $\mu$, $X$ is still distributed as a gamma distribution, perhaps with updated parameters?

$$
p(x|k,\theta)=\int_0^{\infty} d\mu\, p(x|\mu,k)p(\mu|\theta)
$$
i.e. $p(x|k,\theta)=\frac{x^{\kappa-1}e^{- x\kappa/\phi}}{(\phi/\kappa)^{\kappa}\Gamma(\kappa)}$ where $\phi,\kappa$ are functions of $k,\theta$

Answer (score 0):

If the scale parameter $k$ is known then it is still Gamma distribution. For details and more general case take a look at the conjugate prior tables [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior).

Comment: Its true that the gamma is its own conjugate prior, but if you integrate out the inverse scale parameter, you get the compound gamma distribution, which isn't what I want. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Compound_gamma